# Sling shot using SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am working on a sling shot based game developed using `SpriteKit`.
However, I have no idea on how to implement physics.

Can anyone provide any hints on how to start implementing it?

Comment: Hey Almo, I think you are too hard on me. This should be a supportive community not only for PROs like yourself, but also for dummies like me. If beginners like me will be afraid to ask questions, this website will be going down and you will be left here alone to celebrate your greatness... and yes, I have tried to look for other solutions, but what I found was not fit to SpriteKit.

Comment: There is a narrow definition of what questions are supposed to be asked here. http://stackoverflow.com/help Read up. We are very supportive of people who follow the rules. Your quesiton does not show that you have done any research into this. What we expect is "I am having trouble implementing the physics in my game. Here's what I've tried: -small code sample- but the shots are not moving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to get the idea on how to implement such a game.

Let's create a ball we will throw. First, we need a property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) SKShapeNode *ball;
```

Then we have to create a `SKShapeNode` for our ball and set up its physics body:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size 
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) 
    {
        _ball = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];

        // Create a circle.
        CGMutablePathRef circle = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathAddArc(circle, NULL, 0,0, 60, 0, M_PI*2, YES);

        // Set the shape of our ball and its color.
        _ball.path = circle;
        _ball.fillColor = [SKColor blueColor];
        _ball.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);

        // Create a circular physics body.
        _ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:60];

        [self addChild:_ball];

        // Create a physics body that borders the screen.
        SKPhysicsBody* borderBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

        // Set physicsBody of scene to borderBody.
        self.physicsBody = borderBody;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Then let's apply an impulse to a ball with desired `angle` and `magnitude`:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGFloat angle = M_PI_4;
    CGFloat magnitude = 1000;

    [_ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(magnitude*cos(angle),
                                                 magnitude*sin(angle))];
}
```

In your implementation you would need to calculate the angle and magnitude values in `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` methods and apply an impulse in `touchesEnded`.

This should give you a kick start. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed a good kick start.